# Django - Html tags in email template

Tags: django

I' m using Django signals to send emails when a new record is added:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MeetingMember)
def send_invited_emails(sender, instance,  **kwargs):
    host = instance.meeting.host
    subject = "Mizban invition"
    # htmly = get_template('sendingemail.html')
    domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
    context={'host':host,'meeting': instance,'domain':domain}
    html_content = render_to_string('sendingemail.html',context)
    send_mail(subject, html_content, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[instance.email])
```

This code works but it sends html tags in email as well how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Show you html code too. But make sure that your surrounded the `html` code by `{% autoescape off %}` and `{% endautoescape %}`

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter `message` is the message you want to display as *raw text*. You can pass the content of a HTML message through the `html_message=…` parameter of the [**`send_mail(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#send-mail):

```
# …
html_content = render_to_string('sendingemail.html',context)
send_mail(
    subject,
    html_content,
    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[instance.email],
    html_message=html_content
)
```

Usually for the message, one also creates a *text* variant of the message: one *without* HTML that can be used by simple email clients to display the email on a console terminal for example.